# VNCでデュアルディスプレイする方法

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, vnc

ubuntuをサーバー、windows10をクライアントにしてVNC接続をするときに、
デュアルディスプレイで表示させるにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？
viewerは、ultravncまたはtigervncを利用しております。

ご回答何卒宜しくお願いします。

Comment: この辺の記事を読み解くと何か出来そうです。[(Real)VNC Viewer Dual/Multiple Display at remote pc - toggle display?](https://superuser.com/q/1358070), [VNC server configuration for multi-monitor support](https://superuser.com/q/1086133), [How to start a VNC session with multiple monitor](https://superuser.com/q/903634), [Running VNC fullscreen with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10675386/9014308), [VNC viewer with multiple monitors \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9602985/9014308), [realVNC viewer with multiple monitors \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55683306/9014308)

Comment: @kunif 様　早速コメントいただきありがとうございます。ご紹介いただいたリンクの内、下記のページの方法で解決することが出来ました。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675386/running-vnc-fullscreen-with-multiple-monitors　
TigerVNCで
Start viewer.
Press F8
Selection Options.
Select screens tab.
Check/Uncheck Enable full screen mode over all monitors..
とすれば、デュアルディスプレイにすることが出来ました。(少し重くなります)　大変助かりました。どうもありがとうございました。

Comment: その辺の事情を抱えている方はそれなりに居そうなので、公開出来る範囲で条件・状況とか、実現したことの詳細を自己回答にしてください。

Comment: @kunif 様　自己回答させていただきました。大変お待たせしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

解決したので、自己回答させていただきます。

下記のリンクの回答者とほぼ同様の方法です。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675386/running-vnc-fullscreen-with-multiple-monitors

私の実行環境
ビュアー：TigerVNC Viewr 64-bit v1.10.1
クライアント：Windows10 Pro
サーバー：Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

1. Tiger viewrを起動します
2. F8　を押します
3. Options　を選びます
4. Screens　タブを選びます
5. Enable full screen mode over all monitors　にチェックを入れます
6. OK　を押します
7. F8　をもう一度押します
8. Full screnn　にチェックを入れます

これで2枚のモニターに、リモート先のUbuntuが表示されるようになると思います。

Answer (score 0):

2台のディスプレイをA,Bとした時、A:windows、B:ubuntuとしたいということでしたら、BでVNCクライアントをフルスクリーンで表示すればよいです。

A,Bともにubuntuとしたいということでしたら、vncクライアントにそういう機能があればできるということになろうかと思います。
手元に環境がないので確認できませんが、ultravncでは、ultravnc.iniのsecondary=0をsecondary=1に変更すればできたように記憶しています。

Comment: 早速コメントいただきありがとうございます。その方法で試してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。下記のリンクによると、クライアント側ではなくサーバー側でその設定をするとうまくいくようですね（※下記リンクではwindows同士の接続です）。https://qwerty.work/blog/2017/11/ultravnc-multimonitor-dualdisplay.php　私の個人的な都合でサーバー側の管理者権限を有しておらず、サーバー側にはultravncをいれることができなったので、別の方法で解決しました。コメントいただき、どうもありがとうございました。